# how to save user inputs across many activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have an activity which is a form, there are some radio inputs in this form, each one have dependent activity, for example, there is a button named favorite sports, when the user clicks it, he will open a new activity to see the radio inputs as (football, basketball...), - actually I am not the father of this dummy idea, but the client made it- so I want save to results of all user inputs, I am asking if using sharedPreferences is a good idea, or if there is an alternative way to reach what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use SharedPreferences to store small bits of data related to user configuration/basic user input. It can only store basic data types, so if you have more complex bits of information, you should probably switch to another mechanism.

Also, you should not store large amounts of data in SharedPreferences; it's not made for that. Instead, use an SQLite database for a more robust solution.